# Pandas not recognizing the `.cat` command when changing column to categorical data

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with six categorical columns that I would like to change to categorical codes.  I use to use the following:

```
cat_columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
df[cat_columns] = df[cat_columns].astype('category')
df[cat_columns = df[cat_columns].cat.codes
```

I'm on pandas 1.0.5.

I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-54-80cc82e5db1f>", line 1, in <module>
    train_sample[non_loca_cat_columns].astype('category').cat.codes

  File "C:\Users\JORDAN.HOWELL.GITDIR\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\torch_env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5274, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'cat'
```

I am not sure how to accomplish what i'm trying to do.

Comment: I believe the message is clear. ``cat`` applies to series

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .`cat` is not applicable for Dataframe, so you have to apply for each column separately as series.
You can use `.apply()` and apply `cat` as a lambda function

```
df[cat_columns] = df[cat_columns].apply(lambda x: x.cat.codes)
```

Or loop through the columns and use the `cat` funtion

```
for col in cat_columns:
    df[col] = df[col].cat.codes
```